# Is every continuous bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself of finite even order an involution?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

The following question is inspired by Michael Penn's YouTube video [Functions that "cube" to one.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXJCO9E_ixY).

Given any continuous bijection $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ for which the order of $f$ in the group of all bijections is (finite and) even, must $f$ have order $2$ (and hence be an involution)?

In the odd order case, $f$ must be the identity. Indeed, it is known that continuous bijections must be monotonic, so $f$ must be either increasing or decreasing. If $f$ is decreasing of odd order $n$, then $f^n=id$ must also be decreasing, which is a contradiction. So, $f$ must be increasing. If $f(x)<x$ or $f(x)>x$ for some $x$, then one could apply $f$ to the inequality $n-1$ times to get $x=f^n(x)<f^{n-1}(x)<...<f(x)<x$ or $x=f^n(x)>f^{n-1}(x)>...>f(x)>x$, which is a contradiction. So, $f(x)=x$ for all $x$, which means that $f$ must be the identity.

In the even order case, if the order of $f$ is not a power of $2$, then it could be written as $2^km$ where $m>1$ is odd. From this, it follows that $f^{2^k}$ must then have odd order $m$, so it must be the identity by the above argument, which means that $m=1$, a contradiction. So, the order of $f$ must be a power of $2$.

This, however, does not yet rule out the possibility that $f$ could have order $4$ or $8$ or a higher power of $2$. If $f$ has order $2^k$, then $f^{2^{k-2}}$ would have order $4$. So, it suffices to rule the possibility that $f$ could have order $4$.

Comment: By effectively the same argument, $f$ being increasing means $f$ is the identity, so $f$ must be decreasing. But then $f \circ f$ is increasing, so it must be the identity, so $f$ has order 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma.** If $(X,\lt)$ is a finite linearly ordered set, then every monotone bijection $f:X\to X$ has order $1$ or $2$; *i.e.*, each orbit of $f$ has at most two elements.

**Proof.** Let $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ where $x_1\lt\cdots\lt x_n$. The only monotone bijections $f:X\to X$ are the identity map and the map $x_i\mapsto x_{n+1-i}$.

**Corollary.** If $(S,\lt)$ is a linearly ordered set, then every monotone bijection $f:S\to S$ has order $1$ or $2$ or $\infty$.

**Proof.** By the lemma, every finite orbit $X$ of $f$ has at most two elements.